# What is Telerik's Fiddler2 yellow highlight color

Tags: colors, telerik

What means the yellow highlight color on the Telerik's Fiddler2 app?

[image]

All this calls are for images and those 2 in yellow are not presented on Internet Explorer 11 (but ok on Chrome, Firefox and Edge).

Searching the Fiddler's documentation

> The default text coloring of the Session entries derives from the HTTP Status (red for errors, yellow for authentication demands)

This says *text coloring* so I don't know if it is the same 'yellow', because there is no problem in authentication...

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error I believe this is and indication of a protocol error. For example, it will occur when the server returns a `Content-Length: 1234` but terminates the connection after only sending `100` bytes.